# How to find the path to Steam's sourcemods folder?

Tags: steam

How can I find the path to Steam's sourcemods folder? 
e.g. `C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\SteamApps\sourcemods`

Where is this path stored in Windows? I need to programmatically find this path to build an installer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the SteamPath from the registry key at `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Valve\Steam`. Then add the folders `/SteamApps/sourcemods/`

In Qt this is implemented like this:

```
QSettings settings("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\Software\\Valve\\Steam",
                   QSettings::NativeFormat);
QString sourcemods_path = settings.value( "SteamPath", "" ).toString();
if (!sourcemods_path.isEmpty())
{
    sourcemods_path += "/SteamApps/sourcemods";
}
```